# React Native: whole FlatList rerenders on every change, even with React.memo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, react-native-flatlist

I've been struggling with this issue for the past couple of days: I have a list of creators stored in an array, along with another array for followed creators, but when the user 'follows' a creator the whole FlatList re-renders. This is an issue because I'm loading 3 images for each creator, so there's a lot of flickering and lag every time the user follows/unfollows a creator.

I've tried using React.memo but it doesn't seem to be working and I feel like there may be issues in other parts of my code as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Getting data on first render:

```
  useMemo(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    return onValue(ref(db, '/users/' + auth?.currentUser?.uid + '/vendorsFollowing'), async (querySnapShot) => {
      let data = (await querySnapShot.val()) || {};
      let vendorData = { ...data };
      setVendorsFollowing(Object.keys(vendorData))
      setRefreshing(false);
    });
  }, []);

  useMemo(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    return onValue(ref(db, '/users'), (querySnapShot) => {
      let data = querySnapShot.val() || {};
      let vendorList = { ...data };
      setVendorArray(vendorList);
      setFilteredVendorArray(vendorList);
      setRefreshing(false);
    });
  }, []);
```

VendorItem:

```
const VendorItem = React.memo(({ vendor }: any) => {
    // image stuff
    const [imgUrl1, setImgUrl1] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const ref1 = ref_storage(storage, vendor.uid + '_1.png');

    const [imgUrl2, setImgUrl2] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const ref2 = ref_storage(storage, vendor.uid + '_2.png');

    const [imgUrl3, setImgUrl3] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
    const ref3 = ref_storage(storage, vendor.uid + '_3.png');

    if (!blocked) {
      getDownloadURL(ref1)
        .then((url) => {
          setImgUrl1(url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        });

      getDownloadURL(ref2)
        .then((url) => {
          setImgUrl2(url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        });

      getDownloadURL(ref3)
        .then((url) => {
          setImgUrl3(url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        });
    }

return(
   <View style={[styles.eventImageContainer, { marginVertical: (imgUrl1 || imgUrl2 || 
   imgUrl3) && 5 }]}>
          {imgUrl1 && <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl1 }} style={styles.vendorImage} 
   imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }} />}
          {imgUrl2 && <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl2 }} style={styles.vendorImage} 
   imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }} />}
          {imgUrl3 && <Image source={{ uri: imgUrl3 }} style={styles.vendorImage} 
   imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }} />}
        </View>

   // updateStarred basically adds vendor.uid to vendorsFollowing and to the database
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { updateStarred(vendor.uid) }}>
      <Icon
         name={vendorsFollowing.includes(vendor.uid) ? 'bookmark' : 'bookmark-o'}
         size={25}
         color="white"
      />
   </TouchableOpacity>
)
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
   if (vendorsFollowing.includes(prevProps.vendor.uid) === vendorsFollowing.includes(nextProps.vendor.uid)) return true;
    return false;
  });
```

Edit: FlatList:

```
<FlatList
            initialNumToRender={7}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 325 }}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
            data={Object.keys(filteredVendorArray)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => filteredVendorArray[item].uid}
            refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={loadNewData} />}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFfF8F3', marginBottom: 20 }}>
                <VendorItem vendor={filteredVendorArray[item]} />
              </View>
            )}/>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code (e.g., JSX) where `<VendorItem>` is used?

Comment: did you try just using <VendorItem vendor={item} /> without filteredVendorArray here.

Comment: If you only want the "getting data on first render" to happen on first render, use useEffect with an empty dependency array. useMemo will still compute on every render to see if the value has changed. If you need to be 100% sure it only happens once, use a boolean ref and flip it when the useEffect runs.

Comment: Also, what is `ref_storage` doing? Passing in the storage suggests that the storage will be mutated, which can have knock-on effects down the line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a `renderItem` property, you provide an anonymous function which is always created and trigger a new render. Replace it:

```js
renderItem={({ item }) => (
<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFfF8F3', marginBottom: 20 }}>
  <VendorItem vendor={filteredVendorArray[item]} />
</View>
)}
```

with:

```
const renderItemFn = useCallback(() => ({ item }) => (
<VendorItem vendor={filteredVendorArray[item]} />
))
...
renderItem={renderItemFn}
```

The same problem in keyExtractor.

Also move View `View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFfF8F3', marginBottom: 20 }}` to VendorItem because it doesn't have memorization

More examples of flatlist optimizations here: https://www.obytes.com/blog/a-guide-to-optimizing-flatlists-in-react-native

Yet another possible problem is your memoization, if `vendor` is a complex object you need to add a custom compare function:

```
const customComparator = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  // add your logic for comprassion
  return nextProps. vendor === prevProps. vendor;
};

export default React.memo(VendorItem, customComparator);
```

Comment: This is the answer. Anonymouse functions are destroyed and created on every render.

Comment: Thanks! However I've bumped into a bit of a problem. Now it only works half of the time, the other times there's an error that `vendor` is undefined. I think that it's trying to render the items in the FlatList before useEffect has been called – would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MY I don't know all your logic, but probably you need to add a condition of filter your results from API to remove undefined data